# I get a few errors on my code [OptionError: No such keys(s): 'io.excel..writer'] [ValueError: No engine for filetype: '']

Tags: python, dataframe, valueerror

```
There are two errors being OptionError and also ValueError in which my dataframe transfer to excel became unsuccessful

OptionError: No such keys(s): 'io.excel..writer'
ValueError: No engine for filetype: ''
```

Previously on 11/03/2024 the same program had worked, unfortunately on 12/03/2024, it cannot run anymore